# How can I rename files outside of VS Code without the app marking them as deleted?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I understand that if I rename a file outside of the app, that at least by default, VS code wouldn't know that it was renamed and assume the file was deleted. However I wonder if there's a way to change that.

Comment: Did you actually encounter this behavior? Because your question sounds like theory and the screenshot shows untitled files.

Comment: I saved "Untitled 9" and then renamed it to demonstrate. When its renamed its red and crossed out.